# Tableau Crashes when refreshing extract (Custom SQL)

Tags: tableau-api

After making changes to custom SQL and clicking back into a tab, tableau can sometimes crash while creating the new extract, especially large ones.

[image]

Not sure what is causing this but if it happens once it happens every time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can often be avoided by clicking save instead of clicking back into the tab when you finish editing the custom SQL. 
This will prompt you to save the extract and when you do it should finish without crashing!